# Dump c++ class definitions from .exe + .pdb on windows

Tags: c++, pdb, exe

Is there any way to dump C++ class definitions on windows if executable and PDB files are available. I've seen this done before using `gdb` but haven't had any luck doing this on windows. I've tried disassembling executable in free version of IDA but structures tab doesn't show any classes.

#### EDIT:

I found this tool, but it only works for `C` structs: https://github.com/wbenny/pdbex

Comment: Take a look at https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debug-interface-access/debug-interface-access-sdk